# Unable to obtain com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension. Flows described with javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition are unavailable

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, jboss-eap-6

```
21:39:39,453 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (Se
rverService Thread Pool -- 103) Unable to obtain com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscover
yCDIExtension from CDI implementation.  Flows described with javax.faces.flow.bu
ilder.FlowDefinition are unavailable.
```

I'm using Jboss EAP 6.1, with CDI, Hibernate, and JSF 2.2.  I thought it might be caused by JSF 2.2, so I changed the `face-config.xml` to 2.0, but the error still exist.

I followed this guide: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/203257

This is what my module looks like:
This is what my module.xml looks like:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xerces" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.apache.xalan" services="import"/>
</dependencies>
<resources>
    <resource-root path="jsf-impl-2.2.7.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.el.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
    <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl"/>
</dependencies>
<resources>
    <resource-root path="jsf-api-2.2.7.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
```

Comment: I think  the jsf version in your faces configuration is irrelevant. This is about classes or configurations missing from your modules.

Answer (score 0):

How did you switch to JSF 2.2?

If you included jar files in your war/ear file then one of these is loading and trying to load a CDI extension but the jar containing that class is not available. Try removing any JSF jars from your deployment archive and see if it goes away.

If you added it to your server as a module you may have missed a jar file or dependent module that is part of the JSF module from the definition. Remove the changed or added module and see if it goes away.

Comment: I followed this guide: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/203257

I don't include the JSF jar in my war.  I have maven scope set to `provided`.